# Why "Co" expands both "Co" and "co" in AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

Why this expands both "Co" and "co"? I want a register specified variant (only "Co").

```
::Co::
Send, 
(
Constantine
)
return
```

Answer (score 1):

> A hotstring's default behavior can be changed in two possible ways:
>
> 1) The #Hotstring directive, which affects all hotstrings physically
>   beneath that point in the script:

```
#Hotstring c ; case sensitive
::Co::Constantine ; Case sensitive
; ...

#Hotstring c0 ; case insensitive (turn off case sensitive)
::BtW::By the way
; ...
```

> 2) Putting options inside a hotstring's first pair of colons:

```
:c:Co::Constantine ; case sensitive

::BtW::By the way ; case insensitive (default)
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options